# Prevent closing of plasma-desktop in Awesome WM

Tags: awesome

I run KDE with Awesome WM. Sometimes, I have no window (client) open and press <kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to close a window, but `plasma-desktop` is selected. So it kills `plasma-desktop` which makes my background image and other background things.

Is there some way to prevent this for the given window class? Something I can put into the `rules` section of the `rc.lua`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write a function that checks the class of the window before calling the actual `kill()` method. This goes into the `rc.lua`:

```
function wrapped_kill(client)
    if client.class ~= 'Plasma' then
        client:kill()
    end
end
```

Then exchange the function where the keys are bound:

```
clientkeys = awful.util.table.join(
    …
    awful.key({ modkey, }, "c", function (c) wrapped_kill(c) end),
    …
)
```

Comment: Awesome answer (literally). `client.class` was what I needed.

Shouldn't `client.type ~= 'desktop'` work for any DE?